# Is There a Formalization of Cauchy's $F - E+V = 2$ proof?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology, polyhedra, combinatorial-geometry

Can anyone provide, or direct me to a formalized version of Cauchy's proof that for any convex polyhedron with $F$ faces, $E$ edges and $V$ vertices that $F - E + V = 2$. I am willing to accept the polyhedron can be turned into a graph via stereographic projection, and that the triangulation process will be successful. What I have trouble with is why this strategy of removing triangles will always result in a single isolated triangle:

1. Remove all triangles which share exactly two edges and three vertices with the boundary.
2. Choose a triangle which shares exactly two vertices and an edge with the boundary.
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2.

Specifically why can we never 'split' the boundary of our graph into two disconnected polygons in this way?

Comment: You can avoid doing that just by always removing edges from cycles. Note that as long as your graph is not a tree, you can always find an edge which belongs to a cycle....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to split the graph into two disconnected parts. Simply decide not to do that.

It may be easier, instead of thinking of decomposing an *existing* graph, to think of it as *building* the desired graph up from a single triangle by *adding* edges/loops/vertices one by one. Then there's no risk of ending with an invalid graph along the way.